# Need dojo array.map to wait for feature layer query to complete

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, dojo

I am executing an `IdentifyTask` and then using `dojo` `array.map` to create an array of `Features` to pass to an `InfoWindow`.  The stripped down version of my code follows.

```
        var deferred = identifyTask.execute(identifyParkParams);
        deferred.then(function (response) {
            featureArray = array.map(response, function (result) {
               if(test1){
                  testTemplate = new InfoTemplate(stuff1);
               } else {
                  featureLayer.selectFeatures(query, function(featureSet){
                    //processing code
                      testTemplate = new InfoTemplate(stuff2);
                      }
               }
            feature.setInfoTemplate(testTemplate);
            return feature;
                });
                return featureArray;
            }).then(function(featureArray){
                    app.map.infoWindow.setFeatures(featureArray);
            });
```

My issue is if `test1` is false the `array.map` puts a `null` `testTemplate` in the `feature` instead of waiting until the `selectFeatures` is done processing.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that the `featureLayer.selectFeatures()` method returns a [promise](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/featurelayer-amd.html#selectfeatures). So you have to wait till the promise is resolved to set the Info Template. It is nothing related with `dojo.map`. The same as you are doing in the `identifyTask.Execute()` method.
Something like this (I did not test it!):

`var deferred = identifyTask.execute(identifyParkParams);
deferred.then(function (response) {
   featureArray = array.map(response, function (result) {
      if(test1){
         testTemplate = new InfoTemplate(stuff1);
         feature.setInfoTemplate(testTemplate);
         return feature;
      } else {
         featureLayer.selectFeatures(query, function(featureSet){
            //processing code
            testTemplate = new InfoTemplate(stuff2);
            feature.setInfoTemplate(testTemplate);
            return feature;
         }
      } 
   });
   return featureArray;
   }).then(function(featureArray){
      app.map.infoWindow.setFeatures(featureArray);
   });`

Another solution would be to implement `dojo.all` (see more info [here](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/promise/all.html)).

I hope it helps =)

Comment: I tried putting the return feature in a .then() clause of the `featureLayer.selectFeatures()` but the array.map finished processing anyway.  Maybe I did something else wrong.  If you use array.map without a return does it wait forever?

Comment: If you do not have a return, then the returned array will be empty =).
Try to do it simple. Why not just do 2 different mappings, one if test 1 is true, another if ti is false? Just make it working. Then you can just think about a better implementation. 

A nice solution would be using `dojo.when` to let the synchronous and asynchronous calls be handled in the same way. You have to wait till the `testTemplate` object is filled, whether that is using stuff1 or stuff 2. After that, call `setInfoTemplate` and return the `Feature`

Answer (score 0):

I wound up using `array.forEach` and manually creating an array of `Features` with pop-up window templates.

```
identifyTask.execute(identifyParams, function(response){
    var featuresWithTemplates = [];
    arrayUtils.forEach(response, function (result, index) {
        var feature = result.feature;
        var infoTemplate = new InfoTemplate();
        feature.attributes.layerName = result.layerName;
        infoTemplate.setTitle(createInfoTitle(feature.attributes.layerName));
        createInfoContent(feature).then(lang.hitch(this, function(contentString){
            infoTemplate.setContent(contentString);
            feature.setInfoTemplate(infoTemplate);
            featuresWithTemplates.push(feature);
            if(index === response.length - 1){
                if(featuresWithTemplates.length != 0){
                    app.map.infoWindow.setFeatures(featuresWithTemplates);
                }
            }
        }));
    });
});


function createInfoContent(feature){
    var deferredContentString = new Deferred();
    if(test1){
        deferredContentString.resolve(getTrailPointsOfInterestContent(feature));
    } else{
        getBlazeTextContent(feature).then(function(string){
            deferredContentString.resolve(string);
        });
    }
    return deferredContentString;
}

function getBlazeTextContent(feature){
    var deferredBlazeColorString = new Deferred();
    var queryParams = initializeBlazeQueryParameters(feature);
    var blazeColorLayer = app.map.getLayer("blazeColor1");
    blazeColorLayer.queryFeatures(queryParams, function(featureSet) {
        dojoXhr("/trails/trailPopupUses.action",{
            query:{
                parkName: PARK_NAME,
                trailName: TRAIL_ASSOC,
            },
            preventCache: true,
            sync: true
        }).then(function(data){

            var blazeColorString =  "long string is here"
            deferredBlazeColorString.resolve(blazeColorString);
        });
    });
    return deferredBlazeColorString;
};
```

Comment: It seems to resolve the topic, congratulations!